# Homomorphism between Conjugacy classes and the Centralizer

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

Let $G$ be a group and $\sigma \in G$ some element. I want to prove that there is a injuctive homomorphism between the left cosets of the centralizer $C_G(\sigma)$ and between the Conjugacy classes of $\sigma$, that are $\{h\sigma h^{-1}\mid h\in G\}$.

I defined $f(hC_G(\sigma)) = h\sigma h^{-1}$.

I think it is a homomorphism but I couldn't manage to prove it. I am not even sure what is the operation that should be here. Is it multiplication, composition or Conjugacy?

If it is a homomorphism I did however managed to prove it is injuctive. So with this part I am alright.

Help would be appreciated

Comment: The set of left cosets of the centralizer is not a group unless the centralizer is normal in $G$; if it is not a group, how can you have an “injective group homomorphism” from it? And the set of conjugacy classes is not generally a group. So what you want, presumably, is **not** “an injective homomorphism”, but merely a “one-to-one function”.

Comment: It’s not a homomorphism, because neither your domain nor your range are groups!

Comment: So how could I find such a homomorphism. I am even more confused now

Comment: You just cannot if no more assumptions are made.

Comment: There can be no group homomorphism if what you have are not groups. The set of conjugacy classes of a group is **not** a group. The set of cosets of a subgroup is a group with the natural structure if and only if the subgroup is normal. What you are trying to prove does not even make sense.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question. I am only looking for injuctive function between them. And if that is the case I guess I am done here.

Comment: PS: The correct spelling is “injective”.